# A question regarding Japanese sentences with present tense clauses but a past tense main verb

Tags: grammar, tense, aspect

Japanese tenses seem very different from English. Please look at this sentence:

> 考えている最中，電話がかけられました

If translated in English, it should be:

> When I was thinking, the telephone rang

I think the front part of this sentence should be 考えていた最中。

How should I deal with Japanese tense?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25376/3506

Comment: the telephone rang は `電話がかけられました` より「電話がかかってきました」のほうがいいですよね

Comment: @chocolate +1, if you translate `電話がかけられました` into English directly, it would be `the telephone was rung`, which is really weird

Comment: @chocolate, I interpreted that as the やられた kind of passive, indicating that the subject suffered a negative effect. この解釈は間違っているわけですか。

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi 「電話がかかってきました」は、「誰かが自分の電話に電話をかけてきた。」っていう感じの意味で、よく「the telephone rang」の意味で使います。「the telephone rang」はもっと直訳して「電話が鳴った。」でもいいと思います。でも「the telephone rang」の意味で「電話がかけられました」とは言いません。「電話がかけられました」という表現を使う場面はあまり考え付きませんが、「a telephone call was made」「誰かが誰かに電話をかけた」(someone made a telephone call to someone) という感じになって、「自分が電話を受けた」感じではなくなると思います。

Comment: @kevin can you explain what you mean by "deal with"? Do you mean how can you translate it? do you mean how can you come to grips with it  (on an emotional level? in terms of being able to produce it while writing? ???)?

Comment: I'd say 「考えている最中**に** 電話がかかってきました/電話が鳴りました」

Answer (score 1):

考えてい**る** makes sense because 考えている is *modifying* 最中.

Question: What kind of 最中 were you in?
Answer: 考えている最中

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/25378/10859), as shared in comment, can be applied against this question too, I think.

I was not really aware of how Japanese tense works, but every example in the answer sounds plausible, at least for me.

So the short answer for this question would be: it's because in Japanese tense of a clause works relative against the main clause.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm NOT an expert, but in general Japanese either uses past-tense, or no tense at all/the tense being implied by the context.

This feels weird at first, but you'll get used to it.

Also don't try getting your sentences to sound right in English, Japanese is NOT English, and thus you must accept that good Japanese will often make for weird/bad English sentences.

For example, 食べる would mean 'eat' or 'to eat', in English. However Japanese is so context-based that this single verb could be an entire sentence, meaning something like 'i am eating', or 'she is eating', or even asking a question 'are you eating?' simply due to context.

Hope this helped a tidbit lad! :D

PS. It also doesn't mandate a distinction between singular and plural, in fact it lets you ignore a ton of stuff so long as the context implies it.

PPS. Sorry if my answer is a tad 'messy' in its presentation, lol.