# Questions about a correction, nominalizing, and particles

Tags: particles, particle-と, particle-を, nominalization

I was practicing writing sentences and tried to write the following in Japanese:

> I heard he escaped from the island.

I originally came up with

> 彼が島から逃げるのを聞いたそうです。

But then I was corrected by 2 different native speakers. Their changes are in bold.

Person A:

> 彼が島から**逃げるのを聞きました**。

Person B:

> 彼が島から**逃げたと聞きました**。

When I read Person A's correction I read it as

> I literally heard (as in noises) him escape from the island.

I think Person B's correction is more in line with what I meant and I read it as

> I heard (from someone else) he escaped from the island.

Assuming I'm right about the above, I don't understand why と was used instead of を in the 聞きました part.

Now I'm wondering

1. Why was this done or when should I use と over を with 聞く?
2. When nominalizing, do verbs have to stay in their "pure" dictionary form
   or can I change the tense? Could I write the following or is this
   grammatically incorrect? Does it mean the same thing as Person B's correction?

> 彼が島から**逃げたのを**聞きました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already seem to vaguely understand the difference, but to summarize:

- `noun + ～を聞く` = `I hear [noun]`: You hear a sound/music/story/etc. 窓が割れるのを聞いた means your heard the cracking noise.
- `clause + ～と聞く` = `I hear that [clause]`: You hear some fact (via conversations/news/etc). 窓が割れたと聞いた means you heard the news from someone but did not hear the noise itself.

In your case, what you needed was the latter; you heard the news, not the noise.

> 彼が島から逃げたのを聞きました。

Therefore, this never means the same thing as B's correction simply because of を. In addition, Japanese subordinate clauses are [based on relative tense](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25376/5010), so this usage of 逃げた is not natural, either (although understandable). If you did hear his "escaping noise" directly, the sentence by A is correct because (私が)聞く and (彼が)逃げる happened at the same time in the past.

That said, in general, it's perfectly fine to nominalize a ta-form. For example you can say それを見たのを覚えています "I remember I saw it")

Comment: I'm confused. In the page you linked many users state that no. 4 is incorrect or unnatural - テレビが私の国で 《できる》 のは１９６０ 《でした》。But here you say that a similar structure, 逃げるのを聞きました is correct. Am I misunderstanding something? And would 彼が逃げると聞いた have the same meaning as Person B, or is it a difference between a statement 逃げるの vs quotation 逃げたと?