# Tense and conjugation: いないみたいでした v.s. いなかったみたいでした

Tags: tense, relative-tense

Consider the following four sentences:

> 1.誰も**いない**みたい**でした**。ノックしましたが、返事がありませんでした。
>
> 2.誰も**いなかった**みたい**でした**。ノックしましたが、返事がありませんでした。
>
> 3.誰も**いなかった**みたい**です**。ノックしましたが、返事がありませんでした。
>
> 4.誰も**いない**みたい**です**。ノックしましたが、返事がありませんでした。

There are two verbs 「いない」 and 「です」 to conjugate， my question is which verb should be conjugated, or maybe both should be conjugated?

Does it have anything to do with whether the two verbs are simultaneous or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Japanese language is based on [relative tense](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/25378/5010). In your case, you have to choose みたいです ("seems") and みたいでした ("seemed") simply based on the time of your observation, but いない and いなかった are relative to the time of your observation.

1. 誰もいないみたいでした。
   = It looked like there was no one.
   (You investigated the room *a while ago* and thought no one was there *at that time*.)
2. 誰もいなかったみたいでした。
   = It looked like there had been no one.
   (You investigated the room *a while ago* and thought no one was in the room *yesterday*.)
3. 誰もいなかったみたいです。
   = Looks like there was no one.
   (You are investigating the room *now* and thinking there was no one *yesterday*.)
4. 誰もいないみたいです。
   = Looks like there is no one.
   (You are investigating the room *now* and thinking there is no one *now*.)