# 持て余していた vs 持て余している

Tags: tense

**持て余していた**力を、陽菜さんにもらった勇気を、僕のなかで叫び続けている気持ちを、今こそ全部使い切るために僕は走る。

Hi. Why is 持て余す used in ていた form instead of ている form?
If either 持て余していた or 持て余している can be used there, what is the difference between them? I know the former is 過去完了 and the latter is 現在完了.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you understand Japanese [relative tense](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/25378/5010). This 持て余していた is in the past-progressive form simply because 持て余す is something that was happening before the action of 走る happened. In other words, the sentence is saying he had a lot of energy and he has not known how to unleash it *for some time*.

Comment: Thank you. I see. I read that thread before I post my question. So if 持て余している is used in the sentence, what nuance it would convey?

Comment: @chinoalpha Then the sentence only means he somehow had excess energy when he ran. But he is saying 今こそ, so I suppose this guy has been frustrated for quite some time. If that's the case 持て余していた力 refers to that situation in the past.

Comment: Thank you again. I see. By the way, does the original sentence (持て余していた) tell us when his excessive strength/energy will expire?