# Purpose of だった when verb is already past tense?

Tags: grammar, particles

I'm trying to understand this sentence:
言ったのは少女のひとりだった。, which is translated as "It was one of the girls who said it.".

I've understood the first 2 parts:

- 言ったの = noun-ified (past tense of talking) = the talking that happened in the past
- 少女のひとり = a singular girl

However, I don't understand the function of the だった.

[Tofugu says だった is a past tense marker](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/datta/#:%7E:text=%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%20is%20a%20past%20tense%20marker%20for%20nouns%20and%20%E3%81%AA-adjectives.), but here 言った is already past tense, so I don't see the purpose.

Tae Kim says だった means "something was something" but that interpretation doesn't make sense here.

What is the purpose of the だった here?

Comment: Looks like this happens in english too- "What he said was....", that has two past tenses like your sentence

Comment: だった="it was";  言ったの="who said it".

Answer (score 3):

言ったのは少女のひとり**だ** is also a valid sentence. It is understood as a statement of a fact about a past event. 言ったのは少女のひとり**だった** means the same but it somewhat sounds like it is describing the situation at the time when that event happened.

[This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25376/43676) is partially related.

A similar question could be asked about the tense of a cleft sentence in English. I found [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/85561/421317) but it is closed as “too basic”. I don't think it is.