I don’t get his explanations. Need conformation on it about relative and main clause tenses
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/25378/65948
So regarding the first answer:I waited until the bus came (バスが来るまで待った)
Is the “I waited” the main clause? If it is then is that guy is saying that in Japanese we just have to change the main clause into the past tense to get the same results as the English one without changing the 来る into the past too? We change 待つ into the past cause it’s relative to now, is what the post says but what does “now”mean? Does “now” mean when I said the sentence? The 待つ has to change into the past cause relative to “now”(probably like 2 hours before, maybe 10 am I started waiting and after 2 hours,12pm, I’m talking to someone about it), it is considered in the past, is that what he’s trying to convey? The 来る isn’t in the past cause [ 1) we just have to change the main clauses verb into the past for the entire thing to be in the past] but more likely I feel like [2) the bus coming, relative to me waiting, is in the future. I started waiting at 10 am and the bus came at 11 pm and relative to me waiting, the bus coming is in the future, it’s 1 hour in the future] is that what he’s conveying cause to me his explanation was left really vague.
The second is: After eating, I brushed my teeth. 食べた後で歯を磨いた。
The 歯を磨いた is the main clause, right? And it’s in た for cause I brushed my teeth at 4 pm and I’m talking about it to you at 6 pm, so relative to now, 2 hours later, 歯を磨いた is considered in the past(2 hours ago) and suppose I ate at 3pm, due to 食べた後で being a relative clause, it doesn’t have relative to me talking about it to you(6pm) but instead relative to me brushing my teeth(4pm), there’s a 1 hour gap between them and we take brushing my teeth as the “now” and because it’s 1 hour after it, it’s past it. Is my interpretation correct? And also what does he mean by them both being in the future??? What’s with the sudden future thing? “Even if both are set in the future”, what does he mean by both being in the future? It’s so weird?
And finally the weirdest and probably the one that bugs me the most is the indirect quote example he gives.
私はなおみが学校にいると思った。
私はなおみが学校にいたと思った。
I thought Naomi was at school.
Is と思った the relative clause cause it can’t stand on its own and なおみが学校にいる/いた being the main clause of the sentence. The 私は isn’t important cause it just sets the topic and doesn’t actually affect the logical structure of the sentence,right?
Now ,と思った is in the past cause relative to the main clause, なおみ being at school or was at school(more important later) is in the past. I と思う when it’s 8pm and relative to her being at/ was at school(10pm), it’s a 2 hour difference, 2 hours after i thought about it. So there being being past.
That was probably the easier one that I wanted to ask but this one I have no idea how to convey it properly but bear with me.
Let’s take the first example: 私はなおみが学校にいると思った。
いる is in present tense( more accurately the future tense I guess) cause relative to me TELLING it to you about what I thought(10pm), she is still at school(10pm), me telling you about it and her being at school just so happens to be in the same time. So thereby いる being in the present tense.
He gave this distinction about how it’s different to the other sentence: The former implies that the speaker thinks Naomi is at school as he's thinking.
What is the ‘s in “he’s”, is it “was, or is”is”? This has been bugging me a lot.
This sentence is translated to: I thought(relative to was, the to be verb,so it has to be past)Naomi was(was cause English has to make both of the verbs into the past, no other way of doing getting around it, grammar is grammar)at school.
The second sentence: 私はなおみが学校にいたと思った。
It’s the same mostly, と思う happened at 8 pm, なおみ being at school is 10pm and me telling you about what I thought is 10 pm too. But the thing that changed is いる. It changed into いた cause she isn’t at school at the same time I’m telling you about what I had thought (10pm). At 10 pm in this scenario, she’s probably at the park as supposed to being at school thereby having to change いる　into いた cause she isn’t “here” anymore. The previous sentence means that she (10pm) is at school which aligns with me telling you about what I thought. いる here represents she is still here and not anywhere else, that still stands true, that is a fact, so we put it in the present.
Am I right about all of the interpretations? Did I waste all of my time and still getting everything wrong? Am I the only one thinks that he’s explanation is too vague? I would really like an answer.


So regarding the first answer:I waited until the bus came (バスが来るまで待った)
Is the “I waited” the main clause?

Yes, "I waited is the main clause".

We change 待つ into the past cause it’s relative to now, is what the post says but what does “now” mean? Does “now” mean when I said the sentence?

"Now" is the time when the speaker made the statement.

The 待つ has to change into the past cause relative to “now” (probably like 2 hours before, maybe 10 am I started waiting and after 2 hours,12pm, I’m talking to someone about it), it is considered in the past, is that what he’s trying to convey?

Exactly.

The 来る isn’t in the past cause [ 1) we just have to change the main clauses verb into the past for the entire thing to be in the past] but more likely I feel like [2) the bus coming, relative to me waiting, is in the future. I started waiting at 10 am and the bus came at 11 pm and relative to me waiting, the bus coming is in the future, it’s 1 hour in the future] is that what he’s conveying cause to me his explanation was left really vague.

Your option [2) is the correct interpretation.

The second is: After eating, I brushed my teeth. 食べた後で歯を磨いた。
The 歯を磨いた is the main clause, right?

Correct

And it’s in た for cause I brushed my teeth at 4 pm and I’m talking about it to you at 6 pm, so relative to now, 2 hours later, 歯を磨いた is considered in the past(2 hours ago)

Correct

and suppose I ate at 3pm, due to 食べた後で being a relative clause, it doesn’t have relative to me talking about it to you(6pm) but instead relative to me brushing my teeth(4pm), there’s a 1 hour gap between them and we take brushing my teeth as the “now” and because it’s 1 hour after it, it’s past it. Is my interpretation correct?

Yes.

And also what does he mean by them both being in the future??? What’s with the sudden future thing? “Even if both are set in the future”, what does he mean by both being in the future? It’s so weird?

Consider "After eating I will brush my teeth". Both actions, brushing and eating, are in the future, right? However, at the time you brush your teeth the action of eating will still be complete, so you use 食べた. Rather than thinking of it as past tense, it might help to think of た as denoting that the action is complete. 食べた = "the action of eating is finished".

And finally the weirdest and probably the one that bugs me the most is the indirect quote example he gives.
私はなおみが学校にいると思った。
私はなおみが学校にいたと思った。
I thought Naomi was at school.
Is と思った the relative clause cause it can’t stand on its own and なおみが学校にいる/いた being the main clause of the sentence.

No. The main clause is 私は...思った.

Now ,と思った is in the past cause relative to the main clause, なおみ being at school or was at school(more important later) is in the past. I と思う when it’s 8pm and relative to her being at/ was at school(10pm), it’s a 2 hour difference, 2 hours after i thought about it. So there being being past.

I think you are getting confused now. At the time the speaker is doing the thinking, he thinks なおみが学校にいる i.e. "Naomi is in school". It uses いる rather than いた so the action of her being in school is not complete. i.e. she is still in school.
If he says 私はなおみが学校にいたと思った。then at the time pf thinking the action of being in school is complete (いた). So, at the time of thinking (3pm) the speakers believes that Naomi was in school (at 2pm) but is no longer in school (at 3pm). English is rather silly here. "I thought Naomi was in school" is ambiguous if you think about it.

He gave this distinction about how it’s different to the other sentence: The former implies that the speaker thinks Naomi is at school as he's thinking.
What is the ‘s in “he’s”, is it “was, or is”is”? This has been bugging me a lot.

That is, unambiguously, "he is". If it had been "he was" then the sentence would have been "The former implies that the speaker thought Naomi was at school as he was thinking". I don't think I've ever seen "he's " as a contraction of "he was".

Am I right about all of the interpretations? Did I waste all of my time and still getting everything wrong? Am I the only one thinks that he’s explanation is too vague? I would really like an answer.

Personally, I think the explanation is clear, but people think in different ways. What is clear to one person may be gibberish to another. The fact that the person took time to make an effort to answer the question is still worthy of respect and should not be dismissed.

this really helped a lot. Thank you so much for spending time on replying. Just for a confirmation. 私はなおみが学校にいたと思った is the “true” way of saying “I thought Naomi was at school” and 私はなおみが学校にいると思った is “supposed” to be “I thought Naomi is at school” but due to English grammar, the “is” has to be switched into “was” cause main clause being in the past means that in English grammar eyes, the “is” has to change into “was” but that means that the English one has 2 possible answers to it even though the structure indicates one (that being in the past) and it depends on the context on which it is.

Oh and also what’s the difference between 思った and 思っている, I keep seeing them being interchangeable in newspapers and it’s really weird. Is it because that the regular と思った mean “thought” and と思っている means the same thing but it adds emphasis on the fact that they “bring” us to the time that the thinking happens?

And also one last thing, is it more accurately to say that the た form isn’t actually the past tense form that English has but instead a “did” tense cause I’ve seen some scenarios where it doesn’t seem like it’s in past but that it has been done instead

In answer to your first comment: yes, your thinking is correct. For your second comment (difference between 思った and 思っている). I think it's been discussed on this site. It's worth having a look. If you can't find it then please post a new question. I don't feel sufficiently confident to try answering that one. For the third comment, I've heard it said that た marks aspect rather than a tense. I'm no grammarian so it's difficult fpr me to comment further but it certainly helps me to think of た as marking the completion of an action rather than as a tense.
